# Different phrasings for "analyzing of all possibilities in the list"

Tags: expressions, synonyms, phrasing

I'm currently writing a paper in mathematics.

In the beginning of the article I present a big list where each line consists of a sequences of numbers. Through the rest of the text I discuss whether certain subsequences are possible or not, so I must constantly refer to the list in the beginning.

Since this reference is made so repeatedly, I thought I'd better use different phrasings, instead of always writing "analyzing all sequences in List 1, etc."

How else can I state this? "Going through the list"? "searching through the list"? "perusing the list"?

My goal is to tell the reader to actually look at each line in the list and see it for himself.

Comment: A distinc arrangement (of, for example, digits or positive integers) is called a _permutation_.

Comment: If you are highlighting specific instances in the list, you could put a reference after the sentence: .... (List 1, line n). Or you could say X appears in line n of List 1. You may not need to use a phrase like "Looking through List 1" more than once or twice and simply work the reference into your sentences in a more subtle fashion. *Further down in List 1 we find/see...*